# Android drawer not for navigation

Tags: android, user-interface, navigation-drawer

I wish to know if it is possible to do something. I know this is not the purpose of a drawer, but I have to use it something else than navigation in my case.

For example, it want to display some text, with drag and drop, the user can delete text or add new text with a button in it.

I can't display this text outside of this drawer because of UI.

I think it's not possible (I find nothing to do or talk about it on internet), if you can confirm this to me, it will be helpfull.
If you think it's possible, do you have any idea where to start ?

And, can I use a short video instead of an icon for an item ?

Thanks for your answer.

Comment: can you post image of what you want

Comment: Something like that: [link](http://image.noelshack.com/fichiers/2017/02/1484302005-example.png). The user can drag and drop videos in the trash.

Comment: follow tutorials on custom navigation drawers using DrawerLayout

Answer (score 0):

The `DrawerLayout` is just a different type of `ViewGroup`. You can place anything you want within it.

Comment: I will look at ViewGroup for more details, thanks. I hope I will succeed